# if I try bunyan.createLogger my application doesn't start and doesn't show error

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, winston, bunyan

If I try to use winston module I have sucess. Nevertheless, if I try to use bunyan my application doesn't start neither show any error (or I don't know how to find the error).

I am debugging using Visual Studio Code although I don't think it is relevant to this question.

If I just require winston, I get no error. The issue happens when add "bunyan.createLogger({name: "myapp"})" as showed bellow.

I am not interested to compare bunyan with winston. I am defenitely interested to use bunyan unless there is a reason like conflict with other modules (I mean other require showed bellow). I just mentioned winston here because I can use it successfully and I noted that winston doesn't depend on ".createLogger" (at least the examples I have read never use ".createLogger" for winston and always show it for bunyan).

Something called my attention although I don't know if it is related to this case neither I know the why: I always install the dependencies using npm install "the dependency" -s because I want to keep a track of all modules used in my project in package.json. A bit strange to me that I don't see it after npm installed (see my package.json bellow).

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
var bunyan = require('bunyan');
//var winston = require('winston');

var logBunyan = bunyan.createLogger({name: "myapp"});

//winston.log('info', 'Hello distributed log files!');
//winston.info('Hello again distributed logs');
```

...

package.json (Shouldn't winston and bunyan appears here since both were installed with "- save"?)

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "node-rest-client": "^3.0.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to your package.json dependencies for example:

```
"bunyan": "^1.8.8"
```

and do `npm install` and then run your app.

Example app.js:

```
var bunyan = require('bunyan');
var log = bunyan.createLogger({name: "myapp"});
log.info("Hello!");
```

Comment: Hya, unfortunatelly, I am still getting exact same error. In fact, I can see the bunyan module is loaded. I can put a breakpoint in bunyan.js line 1618  and debbug but I can't get any exception. 
Lines 1617 to 1618 are:
info.module.exports.createLogger = function createLogger(options) {
    return new Logger(options);
};

Comment: I've updated my answer. This code represents whole application code and when you exec ```node app.js```, it logs message.

Comment: Probably your app is starting, but you don't do anything.

Comment: Hya, as I declared above, if I change from bunyan to winston, I can successfully log anything I want. I see certain "semantic" diference between both: bunyan has ".createLogger". Whenver my code reaches ".createLogger" it just stop without any exception.

Comment: Have you tried writing ```logBunyan.info("hello")``` after creating logger?

Comment: If you don't have anything after creating logger, it should stop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was neither with Bunyan nor with NodeJs at all. Today I have similar issue with util.inspect. Whenever, in Visual Studio Code, I reach a line with this code, my server crashed without any useful information. I tried to run straight via Terminal (node server.js) and I saw both util.inspect and bunyan.createLogger work as expected. I dived in such scenario (works via Terminal but doesn't work throw Visual Studio Code) and suddenly I realize that there is certain conflict between the TypeScript version in Visual Studio Code and the one installed in my Debian. I am not that expect to explain in better arguments but it may help someone in similar condition. I did:
1 - download the portable version of Visual Studio Code instead of using npm. I noted a small upgrade, from version 1.8 to 1.10
2 - I updated in terminal, npm, nodejs and typescript
PS.: If I had payed more attention I should easily get the point. Whenever I started the VS Code I got "Version mismatch! global tsc (1.7.5) != VS Code's language service (2.2.1). Inconsistent compile errors might occur" and now such message it is over.
This fixed the error.
Hope it helps some future readers.